# How to access R Shiny Input(uploaded) file in another input module?

Tags: r, shiny

Below I have an R Shiny code to upload an input file to the application. All csv files that'll be uploaded will have a column 'carname'. I want to have a dropdown that's able to access and select choices in that column. How do I access the uploaded file in the ui?

Error: Error in data$carname : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Webpapp"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "filedata",
              label = "Upload the Raw Data File",
              accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),      
    selectInput("cars", "Select car:", choices = data$carname, selected = "Nissan Sentra"),
   ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot'),
    )
)

# Define server code ####
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, skip = 15, header = F)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
     if (is.null(data())) {
      return(NULL)
    }
            
    plot_probe(input$cars) #Plotting function in global
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not necessary and also I would say not recommend in this case to use `renderUI`. `updateSelectInput()` will be faster ([Make R Shiny Dashboards Faster with updateInput, CSS, and JavaScript](https://appsilon.com/r-shiny-faster-updateinput-css-javascript/)) and require less rewriting of code:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Webpapp"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "filedata",
              label = "Upload the Raw Data File",
              accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),      
    selectInput("cars", "Select car:", choices = "", selected = "Nissan Sentra"),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot'),
  )
)

# Define server code ####
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, skip = 15, header = F)
  })
  
  observe({
    req(data())
    updateSelectInput(session, "cars", choices = data()$carname)
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(data())) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    
    plot_probe(input$cars) #Plotting function in global
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

What I have changed:

1. In UI part I passed `""` to the `choice` argument in `selectInput`, because as @gdevaux mentioned, you cannot use in this way data from `server` in `UI`.
2. I have added `session` parameter to `server` function - it is necessary for `update*` functions.
3. I have added `updateSelectInput()` inside `observer` - it will update `selectInput` if `data()` won't be `NULL`.
4. As @gdevaux did, I have changed your `choices = data$carname` into `choices = data()$carname`. It is because `data` as a `reactive` you need to use as a function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access the uploaded file from the UI.
But you can create an UI element from the server, and send it to the UI with the functions `renderUI` and `UIOutput`.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("Webpapp"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput(inputId = "filedata",
              label = "Upload the Raw Data File",
              accept = c("text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                         ".csv")),     
    uiOutput("ui_select")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput('plot'),
  )
)

# Define server code ####
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$filedata)
    read.csv(input$filedata$datapath, skip = 15, header = F)
  })
  
  # UI element for select input
  output$ui_select <- renderUI({
    req(data())
    selectInput("cars", "Select car:", choices = data()$carname, selected = "Nissan Sentra")
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(data())) {
      return(NULL)
    }
    plot_probe(input$cars) #Plotting function in global
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```